# Backbone router.navigate doesn't trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a problem with my router not redirecting when i call navigate.

Im running a Rails setup with the 'backbone-on-rails' gem.

The problem seems to be related to how the app is initialised.

**App**

```
window.App =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: ->
    new App.Routers.Main()
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})

$ ->
  App.initialize()
```

**Router**

```
class App.Routers.Main extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    '': 'index'
    'login': 'login'


  initialize: ->
    # Check login status
    @check_login_status()


  initialize_layout: ->
    # Default layout template
    layout        = new App.Views.Layout
    $('#main').html( layout.render().el )

    # Navigation template
    navigation  = new App.Views.Navigation(user: @current_user)
    $('#main nav[role="top"]').html( navigation.render().el )

    # Return this
    this


  index: ->
    @initialize_layout() unless @current_user.get('company_id') is null
    this


  login: ->
    layout        = new App.Views.Layout
    $('#main').html( layout.render().el )

    login       = new App.Views.Login
    $('#main .container-fluid').html(login.render().el)


  check_login_status: ->
    @current_user = new App.Models.CurrentUser
    @current_user.fetch({
      async: false
      success: (data, status, xhr) ->

        # If no user is logged in, and we arent on the login page, redirect to it
        if data.get('company_id') is null and window.location.pathname isnt '/login'
          # Navigate to login page
          window.location.href = '/login'

    })
```

In my router i have an initialise function that checks wether or not the user is logged in. I console.log a simple status to easily verify it, and indeed it logs out 'not logged in'.

Despite that, the navigate doesnt redirect to /login.

If i start backbone history before i start the router, then the navigate part works, but when i refresh the page (cmd+r) then the router doesn't run the index method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the navigation to `/login` doesn't trigger the route `login` is the leading forward slash. If you leave out the forward slash, it should work:

```
self.navigate('login', {trigger: true})
```

Forward slash -prefixed URL means that the route should be found at the domain's root, i.e. `domain.com/login`. To maintain the flexibility to run your application in a URL that's not in the application's root, say, `domain.com/en/login`, you should prefer the relative URL format.

You also say:

> start backbone history before i start the router, then the navigate part works

This is probably not a good idea. I don't know exactly how it "works", but the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) is quite clear on this topic:

> During page load, **after your application has finished creating all of its routers**, be sure to call Backbone.history.start(), or Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}) to route the initial URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i spotted the part about history in the documentation aswell. Currently i made a location.href but it doesn't feel right. There must be a more backbone-friendly way. Updated code.